# Простой Rule Engine

Tags: java, java-8

Я давно не программировал на Java, вопрос может быть глупым (Но усиленно плюсы).
Есть простой Rule Engine, основанный на `Map`:

```
public class TaskSuspenderActions
{
    private static final Map<String, Supplier<TaskSuspenderAction>> actions; // TaskSuspenderAction - просто интерфейс, реализация в данном случае не важна 

    static
    {
        final Map<String, Supplier<TaskSuspenderAction>>
                actions_t = new HashMap<>();
        actions_t.put("SUCCESS", TaskSuspenderSuccessAction::new);
        actions_t.put("SETTING_UP", TaskSuspenderSettingUpAction::new);
        actions_t.put("NOT_FOUND", TaskSuspenderNotFountAction::new);
        actions_t.put("INTERNAL_ERROR", TaskSuspenderInternalError::new);

        actions = Collections.unmodifiableMap(actions_t);
    }

    @NotNull
    public static TaskSuspenderAction get(@NotNull final String internalStatus)
    {
        return actions.getOrDefault(internalStatus, TaskSuspenderDefault::new).get();
    }

}
```

Загвоздка заключается в том, что когда я хочу унифицировать это класс, для создания нового движка (Допустим: `TaskSuspenderActions<SomeInterface>`), во-первых: я не могу подставить шаблонный параметр в `Supplier<SomeInterface>` ибо, если я правильно понял, стирание типа и все такое. Во-вторых: как мне передать ссылку на `new` в Supplier с учетом стирания типа, чтобы добавить новое действие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вам сделать что-то типа этого, и передавать снаружи как вариант:

```
    public class TaskSuspenderActions<T>
    {


        private final Map<String, Supplier<T>> actions; // TaskSuspenderAction - просто интерфейс, реализация в данном случае не важна
        private Supplier<T> defaultAction;

        //Конструктор с пустой мапой
    public TaskSuspenderActions(Supplier<T> defaultAction) {
        this.defaultAction = defaultAction;
        this.actions = new HashMap<>();
    }

    // Конструктор принимающий мапу с экшенами
    public TaskSuspenderActions(Supplier<T> defaultAction, Map<String, Supplier<T>> actions){
        this.actions = actions;
        this.defaultAction = defaultAction;
    }

    // Конструктор заполняющий мапу с помощью переданного кансюмера
    public TaskSuspenderActions(Supplier<T> defaultAction, Consumer<Map<String, Supplier<T>>> actionMapper) {
        this(defaultAction);
        actionMapper.accept(actions);
    }

    // Этот сетер нужен если мапа не имутабл
    public void setActionForInternalStatus(String internalStatus, Supplier<T>action){
        actions.put(internalStatus, action);
    }


    @NotNull
    public T get(@NotNull final String internalStatus)
    {
        return actions.getOrDefault(internalStatus, defaultAction).get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Обратите внимание ваш RE работает как инстанс, не рекомендую использовать статику

Comment: Т.е. наилучший вариант делать map на стороне? Я правильно понял? Про статику я знаю, это был вариант для одного класса.

Comment: Да, в таком случае вы можете кастомно задавать поведение. Хотя в случае с кансюмером  public TaskSuspenderActions(Supplier<T> defaultAction, Consumer<Map<String, Supplier<T>>> actionMapper) мапу можно не делать, вы просто заполняете её с помощью кансюмера снаружи, тогда у вас не будет доступ к мапе вообще

Comment: То есть в случае с таким конструктором ваша мапа будет имутабл т.к. доступа прямого к ней не будет

Comment: Эта реализация вполне рабочая. Можете выбрать как вы будете передавать мапу: 1- мапа создается и сет снаружи происходит; 2-вы передаете готовую мапу; 3-наполнение с помощью кансюмера(в этом случае вам не нужен конструктор с мапой и сетер для экшенов)

Comment: Я что-то пропустил. Где будет map? Я же в любом случае ее создаю и передаю в Consumer. (Я про 3 случай)

Comment: Мапа создается первым конструктором пустая, и потом первый конструктор вызывается третьим. если вам не нужен первый конструктор вы можете создать мапу в третьем и удалить первый

Comment: А, все, я пропустил мимо глаз строчку с `this(defaultAction);`.